# How do I conditionally group by two different columns in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, group-by

Suppose I have a table with the following data:

```
+----------+-----+--------+
| CLASS_ID | Day | Period |
+----------+-----+--------+
| 1        | A   | CCR    |
+----------+-----+--------+
| 1        | B   | CCR    |
+----------+-----+--------+
| 2        | A   | 1      |
+----------+-----+--------+
| 2        | A   | 2      |
+----------+-----+--------+
| 3        | A   | 3      |
+----------+-----+--------+
| 3        | B   | 4      |
+----------+-----+--------+
| 4        | A   | 5      |
+----------+-----+--------+
```

As you could probably guess from the nature of the data, I'm working on an Oracle SQL query that pulls class schedule data from a Student Information System. I'm trying to pull a class's "period expression", a calculated value that contains the `Day` and `Period` fields into a single field. Let's get my expectation out of the way first:

- If the Periods match, Period should be the `GROUP BY` field, and `Day` should be the aggregated field (via a `LISTAGG` function), so the calculated field would be `CCR (A-B)`
- If the Days match, Day should be the `GROUP BY` field, and `Period` should be the aggregated field, so the calculated field would be `1-2 (A)`

I'm only aware of how to do each `GROUP BY` individually, something like for where `Day`s match:

```
SELECT
  day,
  LISTAGG(period, '-') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY period)
FROM schedule
GROUP BY day
```

and vice versa for matching `Periods`, but I'm not seeing how I could do that dynamically for `Period` *and* `Day` in the same query.

You'll also notice that the last row in the example data set doesn't span multiple days or periods, so I also need to account for classes that don't need a `GROUP BY` at all.

**Edit**

The end result should be:

```
+------------+
| Expression |
+------------+
| CCR(A-B)   |
+------------+
| 1-2(A)     |
+------------+
| 3-4(A-B)   |
+------------+
| 5(A)       |
+------------+
```

Comment: So, what should the output look like, from the inputs you provided and with the logic you explained? Also, when you talk about "do that dynamically", what do you mean by "dynamically"?

Comment: By "dynamically" I'm just referring to the fact that I don't think I can hard-code which field should be grouped by.

Comment: Why aren't 1-2 and 3 shown together for (A)?

Comment: Ack! I forgot to include the `section_id` field, which is why 1-2 and 3 are separate. Editing the question now.

Comment: When you group by period and aggregate the days, why don't you also get 1(A) and 2(A) and 3(A)?

Comment: OK... so - you can group by class_id. Will it always be the case that either the DAY will be the same for all rows in a class_id, OR the PERIOD will be the same for all rows in a class_id? And you want to aggregate the "other" column (the one that is not constant)?

Comment: No. It could also be the case that a class spans multiple periods *and* multiple days, but I didn't include that case in the data set.

Comment: So I guess that means there are 4 distinct possibilities for a single section: 1) Single Day, Single Period 2) Single Day, Multiple Periods 3) Multiple Days, Single Period 4) Multiple Days, Multiple Periods

Comment: Please see my edits to see those four cases accounted for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really not clear to me WHY you want output in that way. It doesn't provide any useful information (I don't think) - you can't tell, for example for `class_id = 3`, which combinations of day and period are actually used. There are four possible combinations (according to the output), but only two are actually in the class schedule.

Anyway - you may have your reasons. Here is how you can do it. You seem to want to `LISTAGG` both the `day` and the `period` (both grouped by `class_id`, they are not grouped by each other). The difficulty is that you want distinct values in the aggregate lists only - no duplicates. So you will need to `select distinct`, separately for `period` and for `day`, then to the list aggregations, and then concatenate the results in an inner join.

Something like this:

```
with
     test_data ( class_id, day, period ) as ( 
       select 1, 'A', 'CCR' from dual union all
       select 1, 'B', 'CCR' from dual union all
       select 2, 'A', '1'   from dual union all
       select 2, 'A', '2'   from dual union all
       select 3, 'A', '3'   from dual union all
       select 3, 'B', '4'   from dual union all
       select 4, 'A', '5'   from dual
   )
--  end of test data; the actual solution (SQL query) begins below this line
select a.class_id, a.list_per || '(' || b.list_day || ')' as expression
from   ( select class_id, 
                listagg(period, '-') within group (order by period) as list_per
           from ( select distinct class_id, period from test_data )
           group by class_id
       ) a
   inner join
       ( select class_id, 
                listagg(day, '-') within group (order by day) as list_day
           from ( select distinct class_id, day from test_data )
           group by class_id
       ) b
on a.class_id = b.class_id
;


CLASS_ID  EXPRESSION
--------  ----------
1         CCR(A-B)
2         1-2(A)
3         3-4(A-B)
4         5(A)
```

Comment: To address the presence of the examples in the sample data, I saw it like this: class_id = 1 is an example of 3 (Multiple Days, Single Period), class_id = 2 is an example of 2 (Single Day, Multiple Periods), class_id = 3 is an example of 4 (Multiple Days, Multiple Periods) and class_id = 4 is an example of 1 (Single Day, Single Period).

Comment: As to *why* I want to show a class's period+day this way, it's a familiar format that is elsewhere in the system, so I figured it would be intuitive for our users to read.

Answer (score 1):

How about union with `having count(*) = 1`?

```
select LISTAGG(period, '-') list WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY period) 
  from schedule 
  group by CLASS_ID, day 
  having count(*) = 1
union all
select LISTAGG(day, '-') list WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY day) 
  from schedule 
  group by CLASS_ID, period 
  having count(*) = 1
```